# how to calculate two html txt boxes using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im very new to using javascript and to set up a basis to a program i need im trying to add two values from a text box together. Right now it is returning NaN when i invoke the javascript with my button.

```
    <script>
         function add()
        {
             num1 =parseInt( document.getElementById("num1").value);
             num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML= num1+num2;
            
        
        }
        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <label id="num1">Number One:</label>
    <input type="text" id="num1"> 
    <br>
    <label id="num2">Number Two</label>
    <input type="text" id="num2">
    
    <button  onclick="add()">Calculate</button>
    <span id="result"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique within an HTML document. You used the same IDs twice, and therefor you are accessing the label elements with your getElementById calls, not the input fields. And the labels don’t have a value. The labels should have `for` attributes, that refer the ID of the associated input fields.

Answer (score 4):

ID's must be unique. JS will act only on first ID in page.

You have non-unique ID's: label and input has same ID.

Replace `<label id="">` to `<label for="">`

```js
function add() {
  num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
  num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = num1 + num2;
}
```

```html
<label for="num1">Number One:</label>
<input type="text" id="num1"/>
<br/>
<label for="num2">Number Two</label>
<input type="text" id="num2"/>

<button onclick="add()">Calculate</button>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've made a very silly mistake, your ids should always be unique.

***Just remove the `id` attribute from the label tag.***

To explain you what went wrong in your code is:

`id`s are meant to be unqiue, and when you were seacrhing the element by `id`, the JS was picking the `label` element, and the `.value` property on this element will return `NaN`, hence the output.

You can read more about ID [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id)

Answer (score 0):

I advise you not to declare javascript events inside html elements.

Also, you had an error in the html structure. You have indicated the same label `id` and intup twice. The identifier must be unique, and for the label you need to specify `for` - this means that this `label` refers to the corresponding `input`:

```
<label for="num1">Number One:</label>
<input type="text" id="num1">
```

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let result = document.querySelector('#result');

btn.onclick = function() {
let num1 = parseInt(document.querySelector('#num1').value);
let num2 = parseInt(document.querySelector('#num2').value);

   result.innerText = num1 + num2;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <label for="num1">Number One:</label>
    <input type="text" id="num1"> 
    <br>
    <label for="num2">Number Two</label>
    <input type="text" id="num2">   
    <button id="btn">Calculate</button>
    <span id="result"></span>
</body>
```